# Inside Switch Case - Variable Definition Related

Tags: c, gcc, switch-statement, declaration

In this code, why I am getting i = "some garbage value" as output? I see that i is  being declared but value = 10, not assigned. Why ?

```
main()
{
int a =1;
switch (a)
{
int b = 10;
case 1: printf ("b = %d \n", b);
break;
}
```

Comment: Compile with `-Wall` and fix the warnings.

Answer (score 3):

b is not being initialized. The assignment is outside of any case in the switch, so it picks whatever was in the stack at that point.

Comment: Will I be wrong if I say that,  assignment is being done at the execution stage while the declaration is already done by the translator. During execution a random value gets picked up from stack.

Comment: Will I be wrong if I say that, assignment is being done at the execution stage while the declaration is already done by the translator. During execution a random value gets picked up from stack ? @Pablo Alcubilla

Comment: That's it. The compiler allocates memory for all variables. Then on execution they are initialized.

Comment: Thanks @Pablo Alcubilla

Answer (score 1):

If you want a variable inside a case statement, the right way to do it is:

```
switch(a)
{
 case 1:
 {
  int b=10; //start a new block scope
  printf("b=%d",b);
 }
 break;
}
```

Comment: I know but the solution you have shared changes my needs. The int b declared, in your code, would not be accessible by other cases. Anyway, but thats not the thing I wanted to discuss. I just want to understand that why my code is behaving unexpected. @Akshay Immanuel